# Android gradle cannot find symbol variable

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am currently trying to build an android gradle application but keep getting a gradle error saying that the R file variable symbols cannot be found.

I have tried a number of things to solve the error, but I am afraid I am not familiar enough with gradle to solve whatever the issue is by brute force attempts anymore.

- Re-installed and updated IntelliJ
- Tried changing between Gradle build versions (currently 23.0.2 and tried 22.0.1)
- Tried changing to compile with SDK version 22 instead of 23 with the following error: Error:(3, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. Changing the compile SDK version also causes errors with gradle dependencies.
- Deleted the generated sources folder, and rebuilt the app.
- Recompiled the one and only main activity.
- Checked the XML files for any errors immediately obvious, but could not find any.
- Attempted to use both API level 23 and API level 22
- This project was running fine before I started experiencing problems with Intellij saying that it could not save settings and then kept disabling the android and gradle plugins, which I seem to have fixed now.

The following is an image of the compiler errors shown:

[[image: Gradle compiler errors[1]]

build.gradle:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nz.ac.unitec.application"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.pes.materialcolorpicker:library:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

Top level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout" android:clickable="true"
                tools:context=".AppController"
                android:background="#FFFF">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Undo"
                android:id="@+id/undoButton"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ClearButton"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ClearButton"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/clearButton"
                android:id="@+id/ClearButton"
                android:background="@color/background_material_light"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"

                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/undoButton"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="SAVE IMAGE"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_marginEnd="26dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/saveButton"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="418dp"
            android:id="@+id/sidePanel"
            android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    >
        <GridView
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="252dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridView" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="125"
                android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:background="@color/background_material_light"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/shape"
                android:id="@+id/shapeButton"
                android:layout_below="@+id/paletteColor" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/paletteColor"
                android:layout_below="@+id/gridView" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sidePanel" android:id="@+id/bToolbar2"
            android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sidePanel" android:layout_above="@+id/bToolbar"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/sidePanel">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/background_material_dark" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/bToolbar" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bToolbar2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bToolbar2">
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_brush_black_18dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_weight="0.06"
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton9"/>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_brush_black_18dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_weight="0.06"
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton10"/>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_brush_black_18dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_weight="0.06"
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton4"/>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_brush_black_18dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_weight="0.06"
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton6"/>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_brush_black_18dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_weight="0.06"
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/selectionButton"/>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/selectionButton"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_crop_7_5_black_18dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_weight="0.06"
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/colorPicker"/>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/colorPicker"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_color_lens_black_18dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_weight="0.06"
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"/>
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_brush_black_18dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_weight="0.06"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Application layout:
[image]

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just `clean and rebuilt`

Comment: If still giving error, manually delete files/folders under app\build and retry as per @MD's comment

Comment: Done both of these suggestions, completely deleted the build folder and still the same errors.

Comment: Whats weird is I just checked the R file and the resource id for activity_main is there... infact all of them are there. What directory in the build folder do your generated files end up in?

Comment: Figured out the problem everyone, at the top of my Main activity class I removed the android.R import (not sure how it got there) and everything started working as it should.